# How to reorganize the folders in TFVC

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

For each tfvc project I created, it seems to created a folder as well. In one folder are the folders with the code for all the other projects.
All the folders for the other projects have nothing but the BuldProcessTemplates folder. Interestingly, the first folder does not have the source code for its project.
In Source Control Explorer the box under "Folders" looks like this:

- mysourcelocation\somename

  - ProjectA
  - ProjectB

    - ProjectB
    - ProjectB_Library
    - Project.sln
  - ProjectC

    - etc.
  - ProjectD
  - ProjectE
  - ProjectF
  - ProjectG
  - ProjectH
  - ProjectI
  - ProjectB

    - BuldProcessTemplates
  - ProjectC

    - BuldProcessTemplates
  - ProjectD

    - BuldProcessTemplates
  - ProjectE

    - BuldProcessTemplates
  - ProjectF

    - BuldProcessTemplates
  - ProjectG

    - BuldProcessTemplates
  - ProjectH

    - BuldProcessTemplates
  - ProjectI

    - BuldProcessTemplates

So, how can I reorganize the folders so ProjectB folders with source code are under the ProjectB (outer) folder, rather than under the ProjectA folder?
Or is that even desirable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Team Project `!=` Visual Studio project. A team project is intended to be *a portfolio of related applications*.

Each "Project" (ProjectA, ProjectB, etc) is a different Team Project, and is in effect a totally separate repo. The source control explorer in Visual Studio shows all of them in one view for convenience, but they are effectively independent entities. They have separate repos, separate work item tracking, separate build/releases, separate testing, separate everything.

If the source code is intended to be related (e.g. shared references), you should not put them in separate team projects. There's not really a mechanism to move source code between team projects as they are intentionally isolated.

Comment: They are not really intended to be related, but if the code is properly handled anyway. then I'll leave it alone. VSTS is so confusing!